# ESP32 access point code not compiling

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, arduino-ide, esp32

I'm trying to use the ESP32 board to control an LED, buzzer, and motor (ABA) through an access point.

I got some code from this page:
https://lastminuteengineers.com/creating-esp32-web-server-arduino-ide/
Which is amazing! I changed some names here and there and evrything okay (to control ONLY 2 things).

Now that I wanted to add the 3rd device, the code is not compiling.

I get this error:

```
exit status 1

too few arguments to function 'String SendHTML(uint8_t, uint8_t, uint8_t)'
```

With the line in bold marked.

**server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(ABA1status,false));**

```
#include <ETH.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiAP.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
#include <WiFiGeneric.h>
#include <WiFiMulti.h>
#include <WiFiScan.h>
#include <WiFiServer.h>
#include <WiFiSTA.h>
#include <WiFiType.h>
#include <WiFiUdp.h>

#include <HTTP_Method.h>
#include <WebServer.h>




/* Put your SSID & Password */
const char* ssid = "ESP32DeltaSolutions";  // Enter SSID here
const char* password = "deltasolutions123";  //Enter Password here

/* Put IP Address details */
IPAddress local_ip(192,168,1,2);
IPAddress gateway(192,168,1,1);
IPAddress subnet(255,255,255,0);

WebServer server(80);

uint8_t LED1pin = 25;
bool LED1status = LOW;

uint8_t BUZZ1pin = 32;
bool BUZZ1status = LOW;

uint8_t ABA1pin = 35;
bool ABA1status = LOW;



void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  pinMode(LED1pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(BUZZ1pin, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(ABA1pin, OUTPUT);

  WiFi.softAP(ssid, password);
  WiFi.softAPConfig(local_ip, gateway, subnet);
  delay(100);

  server.on("/", handle_OnConnect);
  server.on("/led1on", handle_led1on);
  server.on("/led1off", handle_led1off);
  server.on("/buzz1on", handle_buzz1on);
  server.on("/buzz1off", handle_buzz1off);
  server.on("/aba1on", handle_aba1on);
  server.on("/aba1off", handle_aba1off);
  server.onNotFound(handle_NotFound);

  server.begin();
  Serial.println("HTTP server started");
}
void loop() {
  server.handleClient();
  if(LED1status)
  {digitalWrite(LED1pin, HIGH);}
  else
  {digitalWrite(LED1pin, LOW);}

  if(BUZZ1status)
  {digitalWrite(BUZZ1pin, HIGH);}
  else
  {digitalWrite(BUZZ1pin, LOW);}

  if(ABA1status)
  {digitalWrite(ABA1pin, HIGH);}
  else
  {digitalWrite(ABA1pin, LOW);}

}

void handle_OnConnect() {
  LED1status = LOW;
  BUZZ1status = LOW;
  ABA1status = LOW;
  Serial.println("GPIO4 Status: OFF | GPIO5 Status: OFF");
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(LED1status,BUZZ1status,ABA1status)); 
}

void handle_led1on() {
  LED1status = HIGH;
  Serial.println("GPIO4 Status: ON");
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(true,LED1status)); 
}

void handle_led1off() {
  LED1status = LOW;
  Serial.println("GPIO4 Status: OFF");
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(false,LED1status)); 
}

void handle_buzz1on() {
  BUZZ1status = HIGH;
  Serial.println("GPIO5 Status: ON");
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(BUZZ1status,true)); 
}

void handle_buzz1off() {
  BUZZ1status = LOW;
  Serial.println("GPIO5 Status: OFF");
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(BUZZ1status,false)); 
}

void handle_aba1on() {
  ABA1status = HIGH;
  Serial.println("GPI35 Status: ON");
  server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(ABA1status,true)); 
}

void handle_aba1off() {
  BUZZ1status = LOW;
  Serial.println("GPI35 Status: OFF");
  **server.send(200, "text/html", SendHTML(ABA1status,false));** 
}

void handle_NotFound(){
  server.send(404, "text/plain", "Not found");
}

String SendHTML(uint8_t LED1status,uint8_t BUZZ1status,uint8_t ABA1status){
  String ptr = "<!DOCTYPE html> <html>\n";
  ptr +="<head><meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no\">\n";
  ptr +="<title>LED Control</title>\n";
  ptr +="<style>html { font-family: Helvetica; display: inline-block; margin: 0px auto; text-align: center;}\n";
  ptr +="body{margin-top: 50px;} h1 {color: #444444;margin: 50px auto 30px;} h3 {color: #444444;margin-bottom: 50px;}\n";
  ptr +=".button {display: block;width: 80px;background-color: #3498db;border: none;color: white;padding: 13px 30px;text-decoration: none;font-size: 25px;margin: 0px auto 35px;cursor: pointer;border-radius: 4px;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-on {background-color: #3498db;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-on:active {background-color: #2980b9;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-off {background-color: #34495e;}\n";
  ptr +=".button-off:active {background-color: #2c3e50;}\n";
  ptr +="p {font-size: 14px;color: #888;margin-bottom: 10px;}\n";
  ptr +="</style>\n";
  ptr +="</head>\n";
  ptr +="<body>\n";
  ptr +="<h1>ESP32 Web Server</h1>\n";
  ptr +="<h3>Using Access Point(AP) Mode</h3>\n";
  ptr +="<h3>Delta solutions</h3>\n";

   if(led1stat)
  {ptr +="<p>LED1 Status: ON</p><a class=\"button button-off\" href=\"/led1off\">OFF</a>\n";}
  else
  {ptr +="<p>LED1 Status: OFF</p><a class=\"button button-on\" href=\"/led1on\">ON</a>\n";}

  if(buzz1stat)
  {ptr +="<p>BUZZ1 Status: ON</p><a class=\"button button-off\" href=\"/buzz1off\">OFF</a>\n";}
  else
  {ptr +="<p>BUZZ1 Status: OFF</p><a class=\"button button-on\" href=\"/buzz1on\">ON</a>\n";}

  if(aba1stat)
  {ptr +="<p>ABA1 Status: ON</p><a class=\"button button-off\" href=\"/aba1off\">OFF</a>\n";}
  else
  {ptr +="<p>ABA1 Status: OFF</p><a class=\"button button-on\" href=\"/aba1on\">ON</a>\n";}

  ptr +="</body>\n";
  ptr +="</html>\n";
  return ptr;
```

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: `SendHTML` has 3 parameters, but you only provide 2. Its clear  that the compiler gives you that error

Answer (score 1):

The syntax of six `SendHTML` you use with `true` and `false` is actually wrong.

By defining a function like this `String SendHTML(uint8_t LED1status,uint8_t BUZZ1status,uint8_t ABA1status)`, you mean that first, second and third input to this function are Status of LED1, Status of BUZZ1 and Status of ABA1.

So try replacing all six `SendHTML` with `true` and `false` functions to this `SendHTML(LED1status,BUZZ1status,ABA1status)`